# WinForms opening the same form multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to open up the same form multiple times while looping. I am not using any MDI form so, is there any possibility to show the same form multiple times?

```
foreach (string report in lstReports)
{
    PrintForm print = new PrintForm();
    print.FillReport(dt, report);
    print.ShowDialog();
}
```

This code is opening up the same form just after the previous one has been closed. What I need is to show the same form instance multiple times instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `Show()` method instead of `ShowDialog()`. That should do the trick.